# Android studio generating at build folder 22.1.0 and I'm using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'

Tags: android-studio

I want to use 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0' and I chaged it from  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.0'. But when building always generates the appcompat-v7 with the 22.1.0 folder inside it.

This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.icab.icab"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile('com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:0.9.9') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile('com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And this is the folder that AndroidStudio generates:

[image]